# After swapping in SSD I can’t get into the BIOS on my Lenovo Ideapad 305 -15 IBD

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, bios, lenovo-laptop

I've replaced the hard drive of a **Lenovo 305-15IBD** with an SSD and added more RAM. Now it won't let me get into the BIOS.

1. In this model to go to BIOS I should use the *Novo* key, but now it doesn't work (it worked before I replaced the hard disk with the SSD).
2. I tried the fn keys too, but they don't work.
3. I tried the power button but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: There is something else wrong. Getting into BIOS ((UEFI) does not depend on having a drive necessarily installed. Restart and see if there is an On Screen message saying "Press Enter to enter Setup"

Comment: Can you explain more? how to restart? My computer doesnt turn on

Comment: It is usually best to make one change at a time, for example, change the RAM and confirm the computer works, and then change the disk drive. Can you put the old RAM and disk drive in and see if it works?

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thank you i change both but it doesnt work

Comment: You may need to machine serviced as it now appears to be a hardware issue.

Comment: Maybe remove just the new RAM that you put in and just try the SSD, similar to that which Andrew Morton suggests. Change one thing at a time.

Comment: I try with ssd and without new ram but it doesnt work

Comment: Could you elaborate on your definition of "it doesn't work"? What exactly is the machine doing from the moment you press the power button? Any output on the screen? Any "beeps"? Fan? etc.. Please provide details.

Comment: When I use the novo key doesnt show anything on the screen.for power key doesnt show any thing on the screen,no beeps, no fan,...

Comment: Seems like a hardware error that needs to be repaired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍battery, it was not charging. After I charged the battery for half an hour,‍ t‍he problem was solved!